# Find everything that's not a float nor it and use it as a separator in split methods

Tags: regex

Floats and ints in regex can be written as -*\d+.?\d* , but how to find anything that doesn't fit to that and use it as a separator in methods like Split.

I know the expression ?! means negative match, but I have no idea how to use it to complex expression. I tried to use it in various combinations with no result.

Comment: If you are trying to do a split with anything that doesn't match a float or int, then presumably you would end up with a list containing floats and ints. No? So why not just match *all* the floats and ints and put them into a list. This is why you need to show us some input and the corresponding expected output and also tag your question with the language you are using just so we can be sure what it is you really want and how you might be able to do it.. As an aide, your regex for floats and ints would not recognize -.12 or -12. or or -1 or -12.34 or 12.

Comment: Please add some example input and desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Booboo mentioned in his comment it is better to just match floats instead of non float text as delimiters in a split function.

Generally you'd use a forward negative assertion for the split.
Like this

```
(?:(?![-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)).)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/UHQRBO/1

```
 (?:
    (?!
       [-+]? 
       (?:
          \d+ 
          (?: \. \d* )?
        | \. \d+ 
       )
    )
    . 
 )+
```

This doesn't take into account exponents or anything.
Just covers optionally signed ints or floats.